# Is there a way to screenshot instagram without making it logging in more than once in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, instagram

Is there a way where every time selenium tries to screenshot an instagram account, it only needs to login once?

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from time import sleep
from credentials import userName,password

exist = ["duolingo", 'duolingobrasil', 'duolingodeutschland', 'duolingofrance', 'duolingespanol']

DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)

i = 1
for ss in exist:
    chrome_options = Options() #
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER)
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    sleep(10)
    username_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='username']")
    password_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']")
    username_input.send_keys("userName")
    password_input.send_keys("password")
    login_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()
    browser.close()
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+ss+"/")
    time.sleep(10)
    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Pictures/duolingo' + str(i) + '.png')
    i += 1
driver.quit()
```

every time I tried to screenshot the output always comes out like this after going into the account's profile.

[image: Instagram login]

Comment: are you using flask frame work? i have faced a similar problem if it is  a flask use the login function under this decorator `@app.before_first_request`

Comment: yes i use flask, this problem is quite a headache to solve @Ramesh

Comment: What is the exact flow of the scenario? can you explain step by step?

Comment: First, the selenium uses the chrome driver to pop out the google chrome tab in which it's going to direct it to the instagram's login menu. after logging it's going to screenshot the total amount of accounts inside the exist array. the problem that i'm facing right now is that everytime it goes to that profile, it always redirected me to the login page even though i've login to the account previously. @AbiSaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using profile - Chrome profile.

I couldn't able to verify this code, because my instagram account has some problems, but this code should work.

There are some flaws in your code, I've modified it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()
# path of the chrome's profile parent directory, you can mention your own
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Temp")  
# name of the directory
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=ChromeData")

# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

username_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")
password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")
username_input.send_keys("<username>")
password_input.send_keys("<password>")
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()
sleep(5)
driver.quit()

exist = ["duolingo", 'duolingobrasil', 'duolingodeutschland', 'duolingofrance', 'duolingespanol']

i = 1
for ss in exist:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{ss}/")
    sleep(2)
    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('./screenshots/duolingo' + str(i) + '.png')
    sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
    sleep(5)
    i += 1
```

Try the above code, if you are facing any issue, add a comment.

Comment: I tried running it, and sadly Instagram is still trying to take me to the login page every time the bot tries to take a screenshot of the profile account. and also i changed this line with this `driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVE)`, since it kept saying that it doesn't recognize service @AbiSaran. nice attempt tho

Comment: You have to do an import:   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service, updated the code.

Comment: I checked this code with another website, it was working fine for me.

Comment: okay i'll give it a try

Comment: okay it works, I had to change a few things but it works. Thx @AbiSaran